# Returning an Array in C#

Tags: c#

I created a method "uniform" that replaces non-numeric characters with decimals and closes in gaps, but I cannot run the method and the output does not return the result. Can someone explain what is causing this output?

```
public class CalcTest
{ 

    public String[] uniform(string[] numbers)
    {

        foreach(string number in numbers)
        {
            foreach(char character in number)
            {
                if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(character) == false)
                {
                    number.Replace(character, '.'); 

                    return numbers;
                }
            }

            if(number.Contains(" "))
            {
                number.Replace(" ","");

                return numbers;

                // This method is supposed to return the correct version of the string array in the parameters
               // without the non-digits and spaces
            }   
        }  

        return numbers;
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string [] numbers = {"1.5", "2$ 3", "12 3"};

        Console.WriteLine(uniform(numbers));

        // Output : And uniform does not exist in current context
        // Output : System.String[]
        /* These are the main outputs the compiler has*/
     }
}
```

Comment: First problem: `string` is immutable. Calling `Replace` and ignoring the return value is pointless.

Comment: In addition to Jon Skeet's observation....first, you can't call an instance method of a class without an instance of the class.  You need an instance of `CalcTest` to call the method `uniform`; secondly the reason you see `System.String[]` is because the `ToString()` method returns (by default, unless overridden) the type of the object.  You will need to iterate through the array and print the values out.

Comment: you should return `numbers` after finishing the work in your loop

Comment: One additional problem in your posted code - as soon as you find one match that needs to change, you make the change (well, not really), and then you return from the method, without checking the rest of the array.

Comment: Final note - you say it's supposed to replace non-numeric characters with digits - but `IsDigitOrLetter` will return true for a digit **OR** a letter, so something like "a21" would result in "...".

Comment: another issue in your code is that you are trying to change `number`, that is an iteration variable in a `foreach`. That is not allowed in c#. If you want to mutate the elements of the array you will need to use a dear old `for`, e.g. `for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
numbers[i] = ...;`
}

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misconception of the Replace method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't reiterate everything I and others put in the comments above, but below is code that will do what you seem to expect.  The biggest change made is that I used [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to make the changes:

```
public class CalcTest
{ 

    public string[] uniform(string[] numbers)
    {

        Regex re = new Regex("[^0-9]");

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            string number = numbers[i].Replace(" ", "");
            number = re.Replace(number, ".", numbers[i].Length);
            numbers[i] = number;
        }

        return numbers;
    }
}
```

The first thing is to replace the spaces, and next all the non-numeric characters are replaced.  The pattern `[^0-9]` matches anything that is not a 0 through 9, and the third parameter simply says replace it up to as many times as there are characters in the string.

The below code shows how to create an instance of the `CalcTest` class so you can call the method `uniform` and then print out the results:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string [] numbers = {"1.5", "2$ 3", "12 3"};
        CalcTest cTest = new CalcTest();

        string[] result = cTest.uniform(numbers);

        foreach (string number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

This is not the most elegant way to do it and you'll wind up with a lot of strings in memory, but it's way past my bedtime so I can't give a more elegant solution.

The output is:

```
1.5
2.3
123
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments in the code. Note that the logic you are following will probably need to be still changed a little to give you the output you expect.

Hint: `char.IsLetterOrDigit(character)` is false for whitespace, so you will replace whitespaces with . before having the chance to replace them with an empty string.

There may be ways to do what you're trying to do in more elegant ways or quite possibly with a Linq one-liner, but I suggest you try working on improving your code little by little.

```
public String[] uniform(string[] numbers)
{
    // foreach(var number in numbers) will not let you change the value 
    // of the number iteration variable, you need to work by array index
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.Length; i++) 
    {
        foreach(char character in numbers[i])
        {                   
            if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(character) == false)
            {
                // when you Replace you need to assign the resulting value
                // or you will just discard it
                numbers[i]=numbers[i].Replace(character, '.'); 
                //return numbers; // not so fast! You're still looping
            }
        }

        if(numbers[i].Contains(" "))
        {
            // same as previous replace, you need to assign somewhere
            numbers[i]=numbers[i].Replace(" ","");
            // return numbers; // not so fast! You're still looping
        }   
   }  
   return numbers; // you just need to return at the end of the iterations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pointless in various ways. Use this instead:

```
public class CalcTest
{ 
    public void uniform(ref string[] numbers)
    {
        string[] ret = new string[numbers.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for(int j = 0; j < number.Length; j++)
            {
                char c = number[j];
                if(!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
                {
                    sb.Append('.');
                }
                else if (char.IsWhitespace(c))
                {
                    sb.Append(',');
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
            ret[i] = sb.ToString(); 
        }
        numbers = ret;
    }  
}
```